# Search and fill the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I require the searching functionality in Excel Macro.

Scenario:

Step 1) Excel1.xlsx have one column as primary key which I have to find in the Excel2.xlsx

Step 2) If the matching is found in the above step, then have to take a value of another column in Excel2.xlsx (from the same row which match the step 1) and fill in the Excel1.xlsx.

Is there any VBA macro to solve this issue?

Comment: If you are going to use macros, you will need .xlsm

Comment: Could you elaborate and revise your question with the specifics of which columns contain the data you need to match, and move?

Comment: Why do you need VBA? Sounds like [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) to me. See link to learn more about the function. In anything that you do in Excel, always exhaust the built-in functions first before you try VBA.

Comment: @L42, is that a rule of thumb that is generally known, or is it your opinion?  For sheets with 10's to 100's of thousands of records, to do something simple in VBA might be a lot less demanding than using functions like VLookup for example.  Where is the line drawn between functionality and processing time?  I'm not arguing, I'm asking.  If a sheet has nested functions and they all are updating with every refresh, vs running the code when it applies..

Comment: @PJRosenburg OP ask a simple question, no optimization, speed consideration, no sheet number or data size. He/She doesn't even post a code to begin with. And yes, it is ROT to give the simplest possible solution. A lot of people here ask the same question *Is this possible with VBA*. And the community often answer, *Yes, but have you tried this?*. And of course if the question is lacking detail, *what have you tried?*.

Comment: Agreed. However, without knowing the names of the sheets, and columns, constructing a formula would just be a copy of the reference material.  The OP doesn't have to select my answer.  I still feel it answers the question, accomplishes the task described, and provides useful information.  With that being said, I DO appreciate your position of being over-complicated, and to use the simplest solution (VLOOKUP). I am not defending myself so much as embracing the ideals you suggested and trying to understand the conditions where one approach would be preferable to the other.

Comment: @L42, specifically, I was asking about this statement: "In anything that you do in Excel, always exhaust the built-in functions first before you try VBA".  Is that your opinion, or a well known fact?  I'm not asking about SO policy, but EXCEL theory.

Comment: @PJRosenburg Yes. If it is already available, why re-create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PREFACE:**   As noted in the commentary by @L42, functions like VLOOKUP are a simpler solution, depending on the project size and need to be dynamic.  That having been said, assuming you have a NEED for VBA, as your question is tagged, I have provided this code.

Without knowing the columns you are trying to use, I have provided an example scenario.   I am SURE you can streamline this more by omitting some of the variables.  I have included them to allow for the names to be set more easily with minimal modifications. Feel free to reduce the amount of variables needed once you understand the concepts behind them of you desire.

**In the example,** I'm using Column A for the lookup value and Column D as the value to be copied to the other sheet IF the conditions are met.  The Name and Date are irrelevant data just to give context.  A & D are the only columns being scanned, or used.

**WARNING:**  THE FOLLOWING LINE CAN CAUSE PROBLEMS IF YOU ENCOUNTER AN INFINITE LOOP.  If you encounter an infinite loop, the normal break mode will not work.  If you don't want that to be included, it's not a problem, comment out this line and you will be prompted with a BREAK when the second workbook opens.  Just hit continue.

*Look carefully at the naming of the sheets. You will need to input your own values.*

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled    'Disables breaking when opening new book
```

**TESTED:**

```
Sub UpdateExternalBook()

Dim s1Sheet As Worksheet, s2Sheet As Worksheet
Dim path As String
Dim s2Name As String, s1SheetName As String, s2SheetName As String
Dim lookupVal As String, moveVal As String
Dim lastS1Row As Long, lastS2Row As Long

'CONFIGURE TO YOUR FILE PATHS HERE
path = "YOUR FILE PATH HERE"                 '"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\"

s2Name = "SECOND BOOK NAME WITH EXTENSION"   '"Book1.xlsm" or "Book1.xlsx"

'Name your Sheets here. 
s1SheetName = "MASTER"                       'SOURCE BOOK SHEET NAME
s2SheetName = "Sheet1"                       'SECOND BOOK SHEET NAME

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled    'Disables breaking when opening new book

Set s1Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s1SheetName)
Set s2Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path & s2Name).Sheets(s2SheetName)

lastS1Row = s1Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
lastS2Row = s2Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

'BEGIN LOOPING THROUGH ORIGINAL SHEET
    For lRow = 2 To lastS1Row
        lookupVal = s1Sheet.Cells(lRow, "A")     'Lookup Value in Column "A"
        moveVal = s1Sheet.Cells(lRow, "D")       'Value to Copy to second book

        For tRow = 2 To lastS2Row
            If s2Sheet.Cells(tRow, "A") = lookupVal Then
                s2Sheet.Cells(tRow, "D") = moveVal   'Copy data from source to target
            End If
        Next tRow
    Next lRow

'WRAP UP AND CLOSE SECOND WORKBOOK

'Activate and close the second workbook
s2Sheet.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
s1Sheet.Activate

End Sub
```

**Original Sheet:**

[image: ORIGINAL]

**Target BEFORE  ---> AFTER:**

[image: Target Before]
[image: TARGET AFTER]

Comment: This is simply VLOOKUP. Using VBA is overkill in my opinion.

Comment: Possibly.  However, the OP was asking for VBA or a macro, and it's possible that they have to dynamically choose sheets, or implement this over other projects as well.  Or if the scope of conditions to check for expand or change, there would be more room for adaptation.  I'm just answering the question as it was asked.  For example, this code would work with LEFT lookups, and doesn't need to worry about Index(Match) or VLookup.  I am interested in knowing the computational cost of each solution over varying sized sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, first use below `DataPreparation` in goal to create dataset, data in column A is your Excel1 dataset, columns B and C are your Excel2 dataset, column D contain solution. My solution works on single Excel file as described above, it uses Excel's `vlookup` function.

```
Sub DataPreparation()
    Range("A1:A5") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
    Range("B1:B5") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array("c", "d", "a", "a", "f"))
    Range("C1:C5") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(3, 4, 1, 1, 6))
End Sub

Sub vLookupMacro()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim rOutput As Range

    Set r1 = Range("A1:A5")
    Set r2 = Range("B1:C5")
    Set rOutput = Range("D1:D5")

    For Each x In rOutput
       x.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(r1.Cells(x.Row, 1), r2, 2, 0)
    Next x

End Sub
```

As new user please take the tour :
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Where does this define which workbook is being used?

Comment: @PJ Rosenburg it doesn't, my goal was to show use of vlookup function inside VBA